# flask how to share variables between controllers

Tags: flask

I defined a variable 'server' in one controller, the value is judge by a cookie key, like :

```
@bp.route('/')
def index():
    depid = request.cookies.get('depid')
    server = current_app.config.get("SERVER_DICT").get(depid)
```

How can I use it in other controllers ?

Comment: [Flask sessions documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/latest/quickstart/#sessions)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `session` in flask .

```
from flask import session
```

You can assign any value to a key of session like

```
session['key']=server
```

and retrieve  it in other controllers by using

```
session['key']
```

And please don't forget to define `app.secret_key`